# Unable to load database in SSDT for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, msbi

`SSDT for Visual Studio 2013` is not populating my databases when am creating a package in SSIS. I can however access these databases in SSMS.

Any help?

Comment: Did you test connection?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked but it is not populating my installed DBs. but only the system DBs